MobX State Tree: get a list of references that are using specific identifier
Well, the question is quite straight-forward.
Assume we have some model with identifier
const ReferableModel = types.model({
  id: types.identifier(),
})

and an indefinite number of models that can refer to this model
const Model1 = types.model({
  ref: types.maybe(types.reference(ReferableModel)),
})
const Model2 = types.model({
  ref: types.maybe(types.reference(ReferableModel)),
})
// and so on

These models can be at any place of the tree.
So, the question is:
Is it possible to list (or, at least, count) models that refer to specific identifier WITHOUT ADDITIONAL FRICTION? I mean, yeah, we can always count such things manually, but I wonder if I'm missing docs or something (e.g. types.refinement) and there is some out-of-box method.
Thanks in advance

In MobX, there is no built-in method that automatically lists or counts models that refer to a specific identifier. However, you can create a utility function to achieve this. This utility function will traverse the tree and count references to a specific ReferableModel by its identifier:
function countReferences(tree, identifier) {
  let count = 0;

  function traverse(node) {
    if (node.ref && node.ref.id === identifier) {
      count++;
    }
    node.children?.forEach(traverse);
  }

  traverse(tree);

  return count;
}


Thank you for your answer, but this is kind of solution I stated in my question as manual. Furthermore, is kinda unusable for me, and the reason is that it is not reactive (might be my fail because I did not mentioned this criteria in my question).
